# Using JSON with MongoDB?

Tags: java, json, mongodb

My application uses JSON objects a lot (org.json.JSONArray and friends). What's the most efficient way to store these into Mongo DBObjects so they can be queried? BasicDBObject can't serialize a JSONArray--there seems to be no interoperability between these two hierarchies at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK it seems there is no interoperability, so I rolled my own. Busywork to get around the type system:

```
public class Util {
    public static DBObject encode(JSONArray a) {
        BasicDBList result = new BasicDBList();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
                Object o = a.get(i);
                if (o instanceof JSONObject) {
                    result.add(encode((JSONObject)o));
                } else if (o instanceof JSONArray) {
                    result.add(encode((JSONArray)o));
                } else {
                    result.add(o);
                }
            }
            return result;
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static DBObject encode(JSONObject o) {
        BasicDBObject result = new BasicDBObject();
        try {
            Iterator i = o.keys();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                String k = (String)i.next();
                Object v = o.get(k);
                if (v instanceof JSONArray) {
                    result.put(k, encode((JSONArray)v));
                } else if (v instanceof JSONObject) {
                    result.put(k, encode((JSONObject)v));
                } else {
                    result.put(k, v);
                }
            }
            return result;
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

com.mongodb.util.JSON has a method to parse a JSON string into DBObject.
The default JSONCallback will return a BasicDBObject or BasicDBList according to input string.

```
Object jsonObj = ...; //any of your org.json objects
Object o = com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(jsonObj.toString());
DBObject dbObj = (DBObject) o;
```

Comment: com.mongodb.util.JSON is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about java mongo driver, but in [c# mongo driver](https://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp) has BsonSerializer class.
You can use it like following code:

```
var q = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyDocument>("{ jsonValueName:jsonValue }");
```

plz check [mongo-java-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/downloads), i thank it should contain the same facilities

also look at [bson4jackson](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson)

Comment: Yes, I could serialize to a string and deserialize the string, but I was trying to interoperate the native objects. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

This works, and throws the question as to why the Mongo folks decided to have an Object return type instead of a DBObject: does anyone know?

A good alternative, if you have a lot of JSON in your app, would be to use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation) for the (de)serialization.