# Converter from Gson to MongoDB objects

Tags: java, json, mongodb, gson

Is anyone aware of a converter to transform from Gson to DBOjects for MongoDB, similarly to https://code.google.com/p/mongo2gson/ but in the other direction (i.e. gson2mongo)?

My aim is to convert a string (which is a valid JSONArray) into a DBObject, so that I can insert it into a Mongo database.  There seems to be a standard technique for converting JSON objects into DBObject i.e

```
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse("some json object string");
```

However, this approach does not work for JSONArrays and there doesn't seem to be a simple alternative.  I've seen a few hacks that work for very simple JSONArrays, but nothing that could be used on a more complex structure. The gson library has some really useful stuff, and in the link above, this problem has been solved in one direction - (it allows you to convert from DBObjects to JsonArrays) but not the other way.  Hopefully that's a little clearer!

Comment: You can convert a JSON string to a DBObject with `DBObject dbo = (DBObject) JSON.parse(json);`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the rapido response! Unfortunately, although you can convert JSON Objects to to DBObjects, Mongo can't handle JSONArrays, (sorry - should have made it clear that I'm using gson so I can make use of JSONArrays)

Comment: @Sam, That's useful information.  Would you mind updating your question to that effect -- preferably with a code snippet so we can better see what you're trying to do?

Comment: there is a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5711200/449553

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JSON with MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699323/using-json-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [Jongo](http://jongo.org/) for interacting with MongoDB since Gson is only a JSON toolkit.

You can save, query and update POJOs with Jongo, that makes pretty much everything you need to with MongoDB.

Gson can be used to marshal JSON to POJOs and vice versa, but when it comes to interacting with MongoDB, you can use Jongo with confident.

They can be mixed too, like converting a REST response to a POJO with with the help of Gson then writing that information to MongoDB with Jongo.